# vuejs animation issue on removing item of list

Tags: css, animation, vuejs2, vuejs-transition

I am trying to remove a list item with some animation, issue is if the removed item is the last one it works fine, but if I remove some item other than the last one animation is not working properly, see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/1003/

js code:

```
Vue.component('hello', {
    template: '<transition name="bounce"><li>{{ind}} <a @click="removeit(ind)">remove</a></li></transition>',
  props: ['ind'],
  methods: {
    removeit(ind) {     
        this.$emit('removeit')
    }
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',  
  data: {
    list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  },
  methods: {
    removeit (extra, index) {
        this.list.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
});
```

html

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <hello v-for="(item,index) in list" :ind="item" @removeit="removeit('extra', index)"></hello>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.bounce-enter-active {
  animation: bounce-in .7s;
}
.bounce-leave-active {
  animation: bounce-in .7s reverse;
}
@keyframes bounce-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.20);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, in the first place you should use **transition-group**, [read more](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions).

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <transition-group name="bounce" tag="p">
      <hello v-for="item in list" 
             :key="item" // You should use your property, (item.ID)
             :ind="item"
             @removeit="removeit('extra', item-1)">
      </hello>
    </transition-group>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You need to define **:key** and you should avoid index and use your property, for example item.ID. It causes some trouble if you use it for removing item.

I have adjusted few things, you can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/1006/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, great tip the one about avoid using index, thx!